# Select dynamically created element with on not working

Tags: jquery, dom

I know you have to use on delegation to select dynamically created element with jquery so I have used this:

```
$(".form_wrapper").on('change', '#imageSelect', function(){
```

However, this is not working and the function is not being carried out when `#imageSelect` is changed.

The markup is somewhat like this but I have taken a bit out for simplicity.

```
<div class="form_wrapper" id="upload">
    <form action="..." method="post" id="audioUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">...</form>
    <form action="..." id="imageUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
        <input type="file" name="img" value="Select an image" id="imageSelect" class="buttonClassic">   
        <input type="hidden" name="purpose" value="track">  
        <input type="submit">   
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: if `.form_wrapper` is also getting generated by dynamic call `.on` will not work. Use some parent element within which you are adding the dynamic content. If you are not sure Use as `$("body").on('change', '.form_wrapper #imageSelect', function(){`

Comment: It is not. `.form_wrapper` is there from page load

Comment: works in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8af6/

Comment: Do you have it wrapped in in $(document).ready(…)?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your jQuery setup logic in the document.ready function. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Setup logic goes here
});
```

Also make sure you've included the jQuery script on the page before your above script.